# Scale rails 3 oauth 2protected API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I need to protect my rails app`s rest API with OAuth 2 protocol. I have tried the Doorkeeper gem but it uses the same server for authentication, I don't think it's good for scaling. How can I config my rails app to use an external OAuth server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I find an answer. Leo thnx for your comments!

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

Resource Server: https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-client

Auth Server: https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-provider

Doorkeeper can be used on AuthServer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can go about this. You can create a new server to handle only Authentication and User Management.

This can even be achieved with the Doorkeeper gem because all you'd need to do is expose the API calls that Doorkeeper provides for you to authenticate and return the token for other authorizations. You would then need from your app server make sure you check with your OAuth server that the token the clients are passing in are valid.

Take a look at this explanation: https://doorkeeper-provider.herokuapp.com/

Comment: How should I config doorkeeper gem and rails app to achieve this? And how can i check that token are valid? May be i should use before_filter to redirect all calls to protected api to oauth server, is there some config or i must do it myself?

Comment: An OAuth server is just an API that you'd have to send requests to. Its pretty much a separate app server that just handles authentication. You'd just have to make http requests to it.

Comment: I don`t understand how to connect Resource Server(RS) and Oauth Server(As) which uses Doorkeeper. I think I need to redirect client request with token to AS server, but I can`t find doorkeeper api to validate token. Can u help me?

Comment: I'd have to do some research on it. I'm not entirely sure how doorkeeper works.